# Does couchbase use Sqlite in 2017?

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite

Im running through the Couchbase mobile tutorial [here](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.4/training/develop/create-database/index.html). The WPF app creates a db.sqlite file. Is this correct? I was under the impression Couchbase had its own proprietary db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a while we experimented with a proprietary DB (ForestDB) on mobile, but it didn't work out well enough in the end so things are back to SQLite.  You can still switch to ForestDB in 1.2+, but I don't recommend it because it will be dropped in 2.0 until such time that it becomes viable again.

So short answer:  Yes, it uses SQLite.

Comment: @borrden Thanks for the clarification, it helps me to understand and pick through the tutorials. Interesting how SQL is being used for NoSQL.

Comment: Is Couchbase Server also SQLite? if not, is it proprietary or a specific DB? many thanks

Comment: Couchbase Server does not use SQLite.  It in fact uses its own storage engine (and which storage format it uses depends on which part is being used i.e. key-value, index, etc).  Coincidentally, the author and father of SQLite is pretty open to NoSQL features in general.  Especially with the addition of json query features in SQLite 3.9.  So while it began as a sort of hack to get things working quickly, it has evolved into a pretty good solution.